# Why can't i insatll auto-sklearn on flask virtual enviroment?

Tags: python, virtualenv, auto-sklearn

Collecting auto-sklearn
Using cached auto-sklearn-0.15.0.tar.gz (6.5 MB)
Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [17 lines of output]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\charukawi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\pep517\in_process_in_process.py", line 363, in 
main()
File "C:\Users\charukawi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\pep517\in_process_in_process.py", line 345, in main
json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
File "C:\Users\charukawi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\pep517\in_process_in_process.py", line 130, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
return hook(config_settings)
File "C:\Users\charukawi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-fv4j7ene\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 338, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
File "C:\Users\charukawi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-fv4j7ene\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 320, in _get_build_requires
self.run_setup()
File "C:\Users\charukawi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-fv4j7ene\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 483, in run_setup
super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
File "C:\Users\charukawi\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-fv4j7ene\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 335, in run_setup
exec(code, locals())
File "", line 10, in 
ValueError: Detected unsupported operating system: win32. Please check the compability information of auto-sklearn: https://automl.github.io/auto-sklearn/master/installation.html#windows-osx-compatibility
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

[notice] A new release of pip available: 22.2.2 -> 22.3
[notice] To update, run: python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip

Answer (score 0):

Windows
auto-sklearn relies heavily on the Python module resource. resource is part of Python’s Unix Specific Services and not available on a Windows machine. Therefore, it is not possible to run auto-sklearn on a Windows machine.

Possible solutions:

Windows 10 bash shell (see 431 and 860 for suggestions)

virtual machine

docker image

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).